# Logging message in Django running through Apache

Tags: python, django, logging, apache2, django-views

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook and I am using Django 1.6.4 (with virtualenv) together with Apache 2.4.7.

I set up a site and want to log from my views some debugging information to my logfile called `homepage.log` (the name of my app is homepage). When I run my site with Django's built-in server all messages are shown in the logfile but when running with Apache no message lands in the file. My project is located under `/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/` (kleyboldt is the name of the guy I am writting for). There I have my wsgi file, my virtual environment called `env` and my actual project called `kleyboldt-homepage`. I would like to log in `kleyboldt_homepage/homepage.log`. My setup is:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/mks.conf**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mks.com python-path=/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage:/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mks.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/static/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt.wsgi

    ServerName mks.com

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/homepage.log
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/kleyboldt_homepage/settings.py**

```
...
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s:\t %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%d/%B/%Y %H:%M:%S',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',


  'formatter': 'simple',
    },
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'homepage.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'kleyboldt_homepage': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
},
```

}

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/homepage/views.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('kleyboldt_homepage')

def home(request):
    logger.warning("test")
    return render(request, 'homepage/home.html', {})
```

When running Apache the warning never appears.

**Update 1**

I changed the logfile to `/tmp/homepage.log` but then Apache shows an error message telling me that a misconfiguration was discovered. Because I set the error log in my VirtualHost to my logfile for my homepage Apache dumped the error message in it.

**/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt_homepage/homepage.log**

```
[Sat May 03 14:00:04.996997 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 16747] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:47319] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mks.com/
[Sat May 03 14:00:04.997084 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 16747] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:47319] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mks.com/
[Sat May 03 14:00:04.997272 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 16747] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:47319] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://mks.com/
[Sat May 03 14:00:04.997295 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 16747] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 127.0.0.1:47319] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://mks.com/
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.015130 2014] [:info] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049] mod_wsgi (pid=16746, process='mks.com', application='mks.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt.wsgi'.
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187017 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049] mod_wsgi (pid=16746): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/kleyboldt.wsgi'.
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187112 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187145 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187282 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     self.load_middleware()
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187329 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187481 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187542 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187652 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     self._setup(name)
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187710 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187746 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     self._configure_logging()
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187793 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187827 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.187887 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.188141 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.188182 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.188218 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049]     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
[Sat May 03 14:00:05.188255 2014] [:error] [pid 16746] [remote 127.0.0.1:36049] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/homepage.log'
```

Obviously Apache does not have the permissions to write to this file. Therefore I changed the group of `/tmp/homepage.log` to `www`. Now writting debug messages to this file works. Now I changed the group of `homepage.log` in my project also to `www`. Unfortunately it does not work. The error log shows that Apache does not have permissions to write in my project folder. What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the logfilename to a full path for now. 
'filename': 'homepage.log', try 'filename': '/tmp/homepage.log',

If that works, you can use os.path to set it relative to your app folder.

Comment: Ok, I tried this. I changed `homepage.log` to `/tmp/homepage.log` but I had the same issue. With the built-in server everthing works. But after I reloaded the apache2 service I got an error message that the server discovered a misconfiguration.

Comment: Well, it is a tricky issue with file permissions. For Apache to be able to write to a file, it needs "execute" permissions on the folder the file is in. Try su'ing as the user apache to see if you can write to the file.

Comment: I changed all permissions to 777, but it still does not work. There nothing in the error log when I search for `log` or `homepage`. I see the results of loading the wsgi file but nothing more.

Comment: @Nick Well, you need to give proper permissions all the way up. /home/nick/Workspace/Web/kleyboldt_django/ so *every* parent folder has to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I fixed the problem by changing the user of homepage.log to `www-data` and reloading Apache2. It could happen that you see an error message when you reload the server and then open the site immediatately.

Comment: The proper etiquette here is to mark it as answer if you were given the answer. Just saying...

Comment: Well, but I should tell the folks out there how I solved it right? But thank you for your remark. Unfortunately I have to accept an answer before the question is marked as answered and this is possible in two days according to the forum rules.